# Auto comment "possible duplicate of ..." missing on voting to close as duplicate

Tags: bug, comments, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, automatic-comments

Please refer to the following question:

[bash: Bash: bad array subscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21401736/bash-bash-bad-array-subscript)

The [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2098236/lrac22) had posted an *[identical problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21400180/bash-bad-array-subscript)* a while back.  I posted a comment referring to the same and voted to close the question as a duplicate of the referenced question.

Surprisingly, an auto comment saying "possible duplicate of ..." was not generated.

I agree that the referenced question shows up in the linked questions list but an auto comment ought to be generated.  Seems like a bug.

---

**EDIT:** I understand that the above behavior is *by-design*.  However, I'd say that the behavior in the following case should also be the same:

It's interesting to see that the auto comment would be generated if you were to add a comment linking to *an answer* and then voting to close the question as duplicate.  For example, observe the following question:

[How to get error code of an app in pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21508646/how-to-get-error-code-of-an-app-in-pipeline)

Comment: Still don't think it's a bug, the algorithm that check if the dupe is already linked to is not very smart, it just look for certain pattern in existing comments probably using a regex.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The fact that I accepted the answer would suggest that I agree it's by-design.  The edit was intended to say that the behavior ought to be similar in case of linking to an answer.

Comment: Oh, fair enough. Cheers!

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've updated the question (please refer to the _EDIT_ part).

Comment: Well, "the behavior in the following case should also be the same" is actually a feature request. If you want to give it any chance better start new feature request explaining this again, maybe linking here for reference. You can leave things as they are, but personally I think that most the dev team will do is mark the whole thing as status-bydesign and close the seal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design as far as I can tell.

The automatic duplicate comment is not generated because your existing comment already contains a link to the duplicate question. Therefore, adding another comment pointing to the same question would be redundant.

Your close vote still counts, and the duplicate banner will be added to the question once it is closed. Your original comment, however, won't be removed, whereas an automatic comment would be.